# Laravel 5.7 - Como faço para finalizar a sessão caso o usuário feche a aba ou volte pra tela de login?

Tags: laravel

Me mandaram utilizar `Session::flush();` no `loginController`, porém, não está matando a sessão.

Comment: Bom ja que não te ajudei vou deletar minha reposta, boa sorte com seu problema!

Comment: depois de horas conseguir resolver meu problema...
tem uma classe chamada  RedirectIfAuthenticated
dentro dela adicionei Auth::logout();
ficando assim..
````
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

Comment: sou novo nesse forum, como faço para por como resolvido?